# Passing correct Parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I'm completely new to JavaScript and have been trying to figure out how to pass parameters correctly. So far, all my functions have been written without parameters and I can do exactly what I want without parameters, but I'd like to be comfortable using parameters as well.

Let's say that my HTML file has the following button:

```
<button name="button1" 
onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('form1').
elements.namedItem('text1').value)">Try me</button>
```

How would I write this function to take this parameter?

```
function myFunction(???) { 

var x = ???; 

}
```

How would I set x to that paramenter?

Thanks

Comment: `function myFunction(value) { 

console.log(value);

}`

Comment: `function myFunction(x) { //do something with x}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
function myFunction(param)
{
    var x = param; 
}
```

Comment: Or equivalently, just name the parameter `x`